# Reduce error and finding convergence with numerical integration in R

Tags: r, numerical-methods, numerical-integration, convergence

I am trying to carry out a 1D numerical integration of the `probability2DBox_free_t` function here below:

```
prob1Dbox<-function(invL, t, invtau, x0, x, n_lim) {
  
  c =  pi * (pi/4) * (t * invtau)
  res = 0
  for(n in 1:n_lim){
    res = res + (exp(-1 * (n * n) * c) * cos((n * pi * x) * invL) * cos((n * pi * x0) * invL))
  }
  return(invL + ((2 * invL) * res))
}


probability2DBox_free_t<-function( t,  x0,  xt_pos,  y0,  yt_pos,  invL, invtau, n_lim,  De,  mut_rate) {
  
  temp_pbx = prob1Dbox(invL, t, invtau, x0, xt_pos, n_lim)
  temp_pby = prob1Dbox(invL, t, invtau, y0, yt_pos, n_lim)
  return((1 / (2 * De)) * (temp_pbx * temp_pby) * exp(-2 * t * mut_rate))
}
```

Fixing `De=25`, `invL = 0.09090909`, `x0=2`,  `xt_pos=5`,  `y0=7`,  `yt_pos=5`, `invtau = 0.0008264463`, `n_lim = 1000`, when I try to integrate the function using `mut_rate = 7e-3`, I do get:

```
0.001997469 with absolute error < 1.8e-05
```

whereas when I try to integrate the function using `mut_rate = 7e-8`, I do get:

```
1180.58 with absolute error < 0.0072
```

The integration result for `mut_rate = 7e-8` is not as expected (values between `0` and `1`), as also point out by the absolute error. Any suggestion on how I can get convergence and decrease error?

I have been suggested to use `Sparse grid` methods, but the only `R package` I found that do that (`SparseGrid` R package) is not very clear on how to specify the domain of integration.

Comment: Your function `prob1Dbox` produces negative values and so your function `probability2DBox_free_t` also produces negative values.  when I integrate `probability2DBox_free_t` between 0 and 1,  I get a (small) negative value   (not 1180.58).

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in the question. I do integrate between 0 and Infinity, not between 0 and 1. The results I expect from the integrand should be between 0 and 1.